RocksDB Put binary data
RocksDB claims to support "arbitrary byte array" insertion. However in C++ implementation I only see the following declaration of key Type Slice:
Slice(const char* d, size_t n) : data_(d), size_(n) {}
Slice(const std::string& s) : data_(s.data()), size_(s.size()) {}

Both accept only string type arguments. In contrast Java version rocksDB can put byte array. I wonder if I can somehow make RocksDB put binary data without converting keys to strings or any serialization. I want to save storage space as binary format seems to be more space efficient.
i have tried `reinterpret_cast<const char *>(out), but when i get value from DB since it is not null terminated i got memory bugs.
As a example,  i have some fixed 16 byte binary key. I cannot put them directly in rocksDB seems to only support string type. I may have to do the following:
void bin_to_hex(uint8_t *bin, uint32_t len, char *out)
{
    *out = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sprintf(out + strlen(out), "%02x", bin[i]);
}

then ,
db->Put(WriteOptions(), handles[2],key, Slice(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(out), MD5_LEN));

Anyone knows how to gracefully insert binary fixed length byte keys into rocksdb?

Why do you think std::string is not a good datatype to store binary data?

Using a char buffer and a length rather than a null terminator can be used to deal with a byte array. Of course you have to remember that you are dealing with a byte array and not a null terminated string and not use a char * to the buffer with functions that require null terminated strings.

It should be possible to provide the buffer using a std::vector, std::array, or std::string.

Slice overview and cautions

"binary format seems to be more space efficient." WRONG. in-memory datastructures have all kinds of overhead to support the desired operations. Dedicated serialization formats shrink your data significantly at the cost of having to inflate them later on. See eg zig-zag coding for small numbers, bitmaps for null values and many more

@pptaszni  because string hex value consume more space. For example ,md5 hex
"00006e8fc5fa39195bc751b7821d6ed1" takes 32 byte in string hex format , but only takes 16 bytes in binary format

@YufeiZheng it's not true, unless you want to store your hash 00006e8fc5fa39195bc751b7821d6ed1 as collection of ASCII characters. Just treat each byte as actual byte, e.g. str[0] = 0x00, str[2] = 0x6e etc ... Ofc in your production code you will use some std::memcpy or std::copy with your output hash.

@AviBerger got compilation error, cannot convert char* to const char* implicitly

@pptaszni i got your point. But how do you insert those raw actual byte into rocksdb?  rocksdb only support string or const char *. I have tried implicity conversion but got compilation error.

If I understand correctly you have your binary data under uint8_t *bin right? Try to create a string std::string myStr(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bin), len); and then use it to create Slice.

Since Slice doesn't maintain its own buffer, you do need to insure the lifetime of the backing buffer is sufficient.

What is wrong with Slice(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(bin), MD5_LEN) since you want the binary, not the character representation. (If you wanted the character representation, the length would need to be 2 * MD5_LEN and you would need a corrected version of bin_to_hex() ) If you start with a char *, you shouldn't need a cast at all. Some playing around with possibilities

And if you want a null terminated char representation, MD5_LEN * 2 + 1.
